# Mockito anyListOf() List<List<String>>

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, java-7, argument-matcher

I'm using `mockito-core:2.8.47` and `Java 7` and want to use in a when and verify `anyListOf` or some other any method.
My Problem is, if I just use `anyList` it says:

> The method name( int, List < List < String > >) in the type Y is not
>   applicable for the arguments ( int, List < Object > )

How can I fix this?

`ArgumentMatchers.anyListOf(ArgumentMatchers.anyListOf( String.class ) )` doesn't work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion you can get away with just the basic `anyList()` method with additional generics information:

```
Mockito.doReturn("1").when(classMock).name(ArgumentMatchers.eq(1)
                , ArgumentMatchers.<List<String>>anyList());
```

This worked for me and also remember to add the `ArgumentMatcher` for the first int variable otherwise Mockito will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this:

1. simply casting on `any()` acts as a sufficient type hint:

```java
Mockito.doReturn("1")
    .when(classMock)
    .name(eq(1), (List<List<String>>) any());
```

2. providing additional generics information to `anyList()`.
   This is basically the same approach as [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294693/mockito-anylistof-listliststring#46295402), only a little more concise as the alias `Mockito` is used, which maps to the `ArgumentMatcher` implementation.

```java
Mockito.doReturn("1")
    .when(classMock)
    .name(eq(1), Mockito.<List<String>> anyList());
```

---

There are subtle but notable differences between the two. Imagine `name()` had the following two overloads:

```java
// Overload A (target of this test)
String name(int id, Object entities) {...}

// Overload B (not targeted in this test)
String name(int id, List<CustomMapImpl> entities) {...}
```

When the second argument becomes `null` in the code under test, approach 1. will also properly match overload A, while approach 2. **will resolve to overload B**. In order match that specific case with generics it would need to be explicitly defined using a different ArgumentMatcher:

```java
Mockito.doReturn(null)
    .when(classMock)
    .name(eq(1), Mockito.<List<List<String>>>isNull());
```